# Facebook webview called twice in Android app

Tags: facebook, authentication, webview

I'm testing my app on a device where the **Facebook** application is not installed.
So when I'm logging with Facebook, a **webview** is opened.
The strange this is that when I've inserted my username and password, after pressing ok a webview is reopened and I've to insert the username and password again and I can login.
What could be ?

```
authButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        authButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        logoutButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // start Facebook Login
        Session.openActiveSession(Login.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
            // callback when session changes state

            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {

                if (session.isOpened()) {

                    accesstoken = session.getAccessToken();

                    edit.putString("fbtoken", accesstoken);

                     if (session.getExpirationDate()!= null)
                            edit.putLong("com.facebook.sdk.AccessTokenExpires", session.getExpirationDate().getTime());

                    Log.d("FACEBOOK", "LOGGED IN");


                        }
                    });

                    List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
                    if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                                Login.this, PERMISSIONS);
                        session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);


                        return;
                    }

                    // make request to the /me API
                    Request.newMeRequest(session, new GraphUserCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                            Log.d("FACEBOOK", "onCompleted");

                            Log.d("",""+user);  
                            try {

                                name=user.getName();
                                email=user.getProperty("email").toString();
                                location=(user.getLocation().getProperty("name").toString());

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            Log.d("ID", user.getId());


                        }
                    }).executeAsync();
                }



            }

        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem on iOS so this problem could be linked.
I solved it by removing the delegate after I received the first response.

So it may be applicable in your exemple like this:

```
Session.openActiveSession(Login.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
    // callback when session changes state
    if (logoutButton.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
         // Its visible so we end the callback
        return;
    }

    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
```

Comment: putting those lines there, I've Eclipse error: Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
  construct(s)
 - Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
 - Syntax error on token ",", ; expected  on public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
       Exception exception) {

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're saving the access token into the shared pref,
and it needs some time to be saved on disk if you don't force it.
You should add

```
edit.putLong("com.facebook.sdk.AccessTokenExpires", ...);
edit.commit(); // <- this line
```

so you are sure that for the next call it will be available